# Persistent Navigation Bar and multiple navigation stacks in flutter using go router

Tags: flutter, navigation

I need help to figure out how to use multiple navigation stacks using go router?
I need a persistent bottom nav bar, and inside every page of the bottom bar I need a different navigation stack using go router.

Comment: Ongoing task: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/99126  Meanwhile there's at least a prototype to try.

Answer (score 0):

This might be helpful:
https://github.com/flutter/packages/pull/2650#pullrequestreview-1144551916

At the moment I'm writing this comment, nested navigation is already supported but if you switch tabs, inner navigators are not maintaining their state.